# Highcharts Y-axis per serie

Tags: json, axis, highcharts

I'm trying to add 3 Y axis, so I'll have 1 Y axis for every data serie.

This is my JSON, which is valid:

> [{"name":"data1","data":[[1361574000000,121201],[1362006000000,122019],[1363388400000,122788],[1363820400000,123740],[1364511600000,124703],[1365112800000,125618],[1365544800000,126553],[1366063200000,127496],[1366668000000,128500],[1367272800000,129433],[1368309600000,130277],[1368655200000,131267],[1369346400000,132191],[1369864800000,133143]]},{"name":"data2","data":[[1361574000000,0],[1362006000000,40.6],[1363388400000,35.7],[1363820400000,41.24],[1364511600000,40.56],[1365112800000,38.96],[1365544800000,39.8],[1366063200000,40.58],[1366668000000,40.79],[1367272800000,38.06],[1368309600000,37.95],[1368655200000,41.31],[1369346400000,40.16],[1369864800000,38.79]]},{"name":"data3","data":[[1361574000000,0],[1362006000000,1.46],[1363388400000,1.42],[1363820400000,1.42],[1364511600000,1.37],[1365112800000,1.41],[1365544800000,1.41],[1366063200000,1.35],[1366668000000,1.45],[1367272800000,1.36],[1368309600000,1.36],[1368655200000,1.36],[1369346400000,1.37],[1369864800000,1.359]]},{"name":"data4","data":[[1361574000000,0],[1362006000000,59.276],[1363388400000,50.694],[1363820400000,58.5608],[1364511600000,55.5672],[1365112800000,54.9336],[1365544800000,56.118],[1366063200000,54.783],[1366668000000,59.1455],[1367272800000,51.7616],[1368309600000,51.612],[1368655200000,56.1816],[1369346400000,55.0192],[1369864800000,52.71561]]}]

The JS code

```
$(function() {

    $.getJSON('testdata.php', function(data) {
        // Create the chart
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {


            title : {
                text : 'Temperature'
            },

            yAxis: [{
                title: {
                    text: 'A'
                }
            }, {
                title: {
                    text: 'B'
                }
            }, {
                title: {
                    text: 'C'
                }
            }, {
                title: {
                    text: 'D'
                }
            }],

            series: [{
                type: 'line',
                name: 'data1',
                data: data1,
        yAxis: 1,
                }
            }, {
                type: 'line',
                name: 'data2',
                yAxis: 2,
                data: data2
            }, {
                type: 'line',
                name: 'data3',
                yAxis: 3,
                data: data3
        }, {
                type: 'line',
                name: 'data4',
                yAxis: 4,
                data: data4
             }]
    });
   });
});
```

However, the chart won't load as soon as I add multiple Y axis. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yAxis starts with 0, not with 1, so you are trying to set last series to non existing series.

```
          [{  

           ...

          } ,{
            type: 'line',
            name: 'data4',
            yAxis: 4, // max is 3
            data: data4
         }]
```

Second issue is to change options to proper format (mistaken by series name):

```
          [{  

           ...

          } ,{
            type: 'line',
            name: 'data4',
            yAxis: 3,
            data: data[3].data //
         }]
```

Comment: I've made the changes you mentioned. Unfortunately it still does not work. Any other tips?

Comment: Change from `data1`/`data2`/`data3`/`data4` to `data.data1`/`data.data2`/`data.data3`/`data.data4` or whatever is your json variable from line `$.getJSON('testdata.php', function(data) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

It finally works now! Thank you!!

Working code (combined with JSON already stated above):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Highcharts Example</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    $.getJSON('testdata.php', function(data) {
        // Create the chart
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {


            title : {
                text : 'Temperature'
            },

            yAxis: [{
                title: {
                    text: 'A'
                }
            }, {
                title: {
                    text: 'B'
                }
            }, {
                title: {
                    text: 'C'
                }
            }, {
                title: {
                    text: 'D'
                }
            }],

            series: [{
                type: 'line',
                name: 'data1',
                yAxis: 0,
                data: data[0].data,
            }, {
                type: 'line',
                name: 'data2',
                yAxis: 1,
                data: data[1].data
            }, {
                type: 'line',
                name: 'data3',
                yAxis: 2,
                data: data[2].data
            }, {
                type: 'line',
                name: 'data4',
                yAxis: 3,
                data: data[3].data
             }]
    });
   });
});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="container" style="height: 500px; min-width: 500px"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```